# How does the React render actually translate to Browser painting elements on screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, browser

I have created a small **React** example where I am simulating a `state` change every **1s**.

I have enabled **Show paint flashing rectangles** from **Chrome developer tools** to examine the UI.

After each second, I am getting a new **paint** signified by the **greenish** color.

Following is the code for React App without memo :-

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [_, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setState((state) => state + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return <DIV />;
}

const DIV = () => {
  console.log("render");
  return <div className="App">Text</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Following is the `React.memo` variation :-

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [_, setState] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setState((state) => state + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return <DIV />;
}

const DIV = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("render");
  return <div className="App">Text</div>;
});

export default App;
```

App CSS :-

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
```

In both of the above cases, the **paint flashing** occurs on the UI.

- In first scenario, why does each **render** cause the **black** div to be painted again ?
- In second scenario, there is no **render** due to `React.memo` but still **black** div is painted again ?

How does the **React render** actually translate to **Browser painting elements** on screen ?

Below is the gif for it :-

[image: Painting]

Comment: are you able to reproduce it? i tried reproducing it on codesandbox and cannot replicate the paint flashing that you showed

Comment: @codemax Able to reproduce it locally. **codesandbox** and **stackoverflow's** editor don't seem to give the real picture. They will have their own **paint flashing** for some-cases and not in some. Locally I have tried with both **development** build and **production** build.